# CSS COMO MUDAR A COR DO LINK DEPOIS QUE FOI ACESSADO?

Tags: css

Pessoal quero mudar a cor de links depois que ele for acessado e ao voltar a pagina ele fique com uma cor identificando que foi acessado, mas quero um codigo css para o tema dooplay, nao sei como realizar isso.

Exemplo de um site que ja faz o que quero fazer: https://maxseries.me/series-e-animes/lucifer/

Clique em um episodio depois volte e perceba que vai estar marcado o link que você visitou.

Utilizei o seguinte codigo:

a:visited {
padding-left: 14px;
background: url(images/checkmark.gif) left no-repeat;
}

Como não entendo muito bem de css nao consegui fazer o mesmo como no site que dei de exemplo.

Se o codigo estiver errado me avisem.

Comment: Como assim ? Você gostaria de clicar em um link e ir para outra página e, após isso, voltar para a página anterior e esse link que você clicou anteriormente fiquei com uma "marcação de clicado" ? Poste mais detalhes pra darmos uma olhada. Principalmente alguma parte de código ou revise um pouco seu texto.

Comment: Olá José. Dooplay seria o tema para Wordpress? Sendo esse o caso a sua dificuldade não está clara e nem fácil de saber aonde precisa que isso funcione ou qual(is) link(s) você precisa que o efeito seja aplicado, É importante você [edit], esclarecer os pontos de forma simples e objetiva e adicionar **um [mcve] do problema**, ou seja, um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma clara e objetiva o que precisa. **NÃO DELETE E NEM RECRIE A PERGUNTA, APENAS EDITE E AGUARDE O PROCESSO DE REABERTURA**. Obrigado por compreender.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
a:visited {
    /* estilos para links visitados */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Vou mostrar um exemplo com um link dentro de um parágrafo:**

```css
 a.link:visited {
 color: #232020;
```

```html
<body>
    <p><a class="link" href="#">Nome do link</a></p>
</body
```

Comment: Dei -1 porque achei desnecessário criar uma classe "link" para um a-href. É como criar uma classe "paragrafo" para um p, essa classificação já está implícita. Classes se usa para classificar de outras formas. Então a resposta está efetivamente deseducando quem lê.